# Delete everything except all surrounded by ()

Tags: regex, linux, bash

Let's say i have file like this

```
adsf(2)

af(3)

g5a(65)

aafg(1245)

a(3)df
```

How can i get from this only numbers between ( and ) ?

using BASH

Answer (score 4):

A couple of solution comes to mind. Some of them handles the empty lines correctly, others not. Trivial to remove those though, using either `grep -v '^$'` or `sed '/^$/d'`.

sed

```
sed 's|.*(\([0-9]\+\).*|\1|' input
```

awk

```
awk -F'[()]' '/./{print $2}' input
2
3
65
1245
3
```

pure bash

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="()"

while read a b; do
    if [ -z $b ]; then
        continue
    fi
    echo $b
done < input
```

and finally, using `tr`

```
cat input | tr -d '[a-z()]'
```

Comment: the "pure bash" version doesn't quite work for the last line of the input file (it prints "3  df")

Comment: @eugene y - it does work for me, I only get the pure numbers. On ubuntu, running bash 4.1.5

Comment: The awk option `-F` is shorhand for setting FS in the BEGIN block: `awk -F '[()]' '/./ {print $2}'`

Comment: @glenn jackman - I always though that you had to use `FS` in order to split on regexp, learnt something new. Answer updated. Thanks!

Comment: The `tr` answer won't produce the correct output if the prefix contains digits, as in "g5a(65)"

Comment: Pure Bash with regex: `while read line; do [[ "$line" =~ .*\(([0-9]+)\) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done < input`.

Comment: @glenn jackman - correct (again) tr solution is not perfect. @janmoesen - nice, post and I'll upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line; do
    if [ -z "$line" ]; then
        continue
    fi  
    line=${line#*(}
    line=${line%)*}
    echo $line
done < file
```

Comment: This will give false positives if there is `foo(bar)`, for instance. No idea if the asker's file ever will contain such lines.

Answer (score 1):

Positive [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ echo $'a1b(2)c\nd3e(456)fg7' | grep -Poe '(?<=\()[0-9]*(?=\))'
2
456
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
while read line ; do
  [[ $line =~ .*\(([[:digit:]]+)\).* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < file
```